# Find min value excluding zero in nested lists

Tags: python, min

How do I find min values excluding zero in this list which has nested lists below?

```
lst = [[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried this function but it will show 0 obviously.

```
lst = [[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]  

lst = list(map(min, *lst))
print(lst)

[0, 0, 0]
```

the list should be viewed as

```
[1, 5, 7], 
[8, 6, 3], 
[0, 2, 4], 
[0, 0, 0]
```

so the expected output should be

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: There is always one nested list or can be several?

Comment: @Alderven one only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an option:

```
lst = [[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]
m = list(min(n for n in col if n != 0) for col in zip(*lst))
print(m) # [1, 2, 3]
```

if i understand correctly, you want the minimum of each 'column' of your nested list. `zip(*lst)` lets you iterate over columns; then i just select the minimum of those.

Comment: Sorted isn't needed, edited my question again for the sake of it.

Comment: just making a comprehension so result would be [1, 2, 3]

Comment: yeah that's it, maybe i didn't explain well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested list comprehension, filtering the zero values out of the nested lists first and only getting the min from lists that still have any elements left.

```
>>> lst = [[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]  
>>> In [3]: [min(sub) for sub in ([x for x in sub if x] for sub in zip(*lst)) if sub]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: but it should be [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @user7716943 Okay, _why_ should it be `[1, 2, 3]`? That's not the order of the min elements in the lists. If you just want the min elements in sorted order, use `sorted`.

Comment: no it is not about sorted... you need to view it such that you will compare each of those nested list for each index to get a min value..... so you get a min value from lst[0][0] & lst[1][0] & lst [2][0] and so on.....

Comment: @user7716943 Ah, now I see. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]  
flat_list =[i for j in lst for i in j]
flat_list.sort()
flat_list=list(set(flat_list))
min_val = flat_list[0] if flat_list[0]!=0 else flat_list[1]
print(min_val)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `chain`, filter (or comprehension), and min:

```
min(x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst) if x != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little too much `comprehensions` : ),

```
>>> x
[[1, 5, 7], [8, 6, 3], [0, 2, 4], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> vals = map(min, [k for k in [[z for z in y if z != 0] for y in x] if k])
>>> sorted(vals)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Too much ? Okay, less `comprehensions` :),

```
>>> vals = map(min, [[v for v in y if v != 0] for y in x if not all(k==0 for k in y)])
>>> sorted(vals)
[1, 2, 3]
```